# Ideas on how to install Windows 7 on a MacBook Pro (2010) with broken display

Tags: windows-7, macbook-pro, windows-installation

The display of my MacBook Pro 13" (2010 model) is broken and I would like to install Windows 7 Pro on the device.

I also have a Cinema Display which connects to the MBP. However, I cannot get the MBP to display the Windows 7 installation routines on the Cinema Display during install. I tried putting the MBP in ClamShell mode (using external USB keyboard and mouse) but the Cinema Display will no show anything.

Any ideas on how to install Windows 7 on a Mac with a broken display?

Things I have at hand:

- MacBook Pro 13" with broken display
- a 2nd MacBook Pro 15" which works
  fine
- LED Cinema Display
- Windows 7 Pro x64 Install DVD
- USB Stick 16 GB

Could I swap HDDs and install Windows on the 15" MBP and then - after Windows has installed - swap back the HDDs? Apart from a larger display, both MBPs only differ in RAM size and CPU speed.

I would really like to avoid having to create an answer file using the WAIK for an unattended installation - if that is possible?

Comment: If they're same model [or even close] you could probably disk swap... not sure how you'd persuade Windows to work on the functioning screen, though; that might be task 2...

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you for your affirmation. Switching between internal and external screens is easy in Windows (even when your primary screen is broken like mine): just press WIN + P to toggle display modes...

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question by trail and error.

I ended up removing my broken build in display entirely and then operating the MBP with the Cinema Display.

All other attempts (closing the lid immediately after boot up to toggle to external display, operating the MBP in ClamShell mode, etc.) did not work.